# Columns in RWD grid view (CSS Responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am learning CSS and have come across to this [lesson](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_cols) in [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp). I am struggling to understand what are the purposes of having so many column classes in grid view:

```
....
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
......
```

And why the two `div` elements are put inside `colulmn-3` and `colulmn-9`, why others are skipped?

```
  <div class="col-3">
  <ul>
......
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-9">
.....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a CSS grid system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462662/what-is-a-css-grid-system)

Comment: pintxo, please don't say that. Its not the duplicate. Have you even gone through my question details?

Comment: such column classes are most often part of a CSS grid system, so I reason it's a good idea to point you to read about what a grid system is.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain it. please visit [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLp3Q.png) Webseite for more information.

grid view is used in 99% cases to make a website responsiv.

row has 12 column per default. and `<div class="col-3">` means that div should only use 3 column of 12. And the other `<div class="col-9">` should use 9 column of 12 
so you hahe 3 + 9 = 12 column.
[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to learn and know. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So

```
12 = 100%
9 + 3 = 12 (100%)
```

If you want to have a full width, you need to have a total of 12 and that will give you 100% of container

If you want to have 3 columns you will use 4 + 4 + 4 = 12

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4">
   <div class="col-4">
   <div class="col-4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple math while taking columns classes div.

Percentages add up to make 100% . Like 25% + 75% = 100%

**Examples**

**2 columns: 25% on left, 75% on right**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">..</div>
    <div class="col-9">..</div>
</div>
```

**2 columns: 50% on left, 50% on right**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">..</div>
    <div class="col-6">..</div>
</div>
```

**3 columns: 33% each**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">..</div>
    <div class="col-4">..</div>
    <div class="col-4">..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you have explained it well, although I must accept only one answer, therefore I have accepted MKAD.

Comment: Welcome. No Problems :)